# How to obtain a Lie algebra homomorphism from a Lie group homomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

In class we learn a theorem tells us one can cook up a Lie algebra from a Lie group:

If

$f: G\to H$ is a homomorphism of a Lie group then

$T_I f: T_I G\to T_I H$ is a homomorphism of Lie algebra.

I have a version of the proof in hand writing which I don't quite understand, so I would really like to see another version of the proof of this theorem.

Comment: You know that $f(gg')=f(g)f(g')$, what do you get when you "differentiate" this equation?

Comment: This isn't a way to "cook up" a Lie algebra from a Lie group, since one must have the Lie algebras in hand to make sense of the induced map. A standard proof of this is given, for example, after the statement of Theorem 4.25 in Lee's *Intro. to Smooth Manifolds*.

Comment: @Quimey If it is a matrix Lie group, you could do that. In general, I think you will have to use the left-invariant vector fields definition of the Lie algebra.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the construction intuitively think of the Lie algebra $T_I G$ as an infinitesimal neighborhood of the identity in $G$. Then the map $T_I f$ is just the restriction of $f$ to the infinitesimal neighborhood. This can actually be formalized in the context of dual numbers, but in any case once you understand the intuition behind it you should be able to construct/understand the proof as well.